# Google requiring certain properties for certain types when adding Schema.org markup?

Tags: schema.org, google-rich-snippets, accelerated-mobile-page

I tried to add Schema.org markup on my site, with the type `Article`, then adding some properties on it, when checked on Google Structured Data Testing Tool, it said required certain properties, like `dataPublished`, `author` etc.

[image: Errors/warnings in the SDTT]

I can add some properties to meet the requirement, but not all of them. Is this requirement real? I mean really required by the rule? Or just Google rule? I came across this page https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/articles It said for non-AMP, those requirements are only optional (ignored or recommended, non of them said required for non-AMP).

This get me confused, anyone knows about this, what's your opinion? Do Google Structured Data Testing Tool already include AMP requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are required/recommended for getting one of Google’s search features.

If you don’t want that Google search feature, or if you can’t provide all necessary properties, you can keep everything like it is and ignore the errors and warnings.

#### Related answers

- [Should Schema.org dateModified have some default value if not available?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36681182/1591669)
- [Schema.org/Microdata markup for list of recent posts without providing “author” / “publisher”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35629108/1591669)
- [Do I have to create new visible elements to abide by Google's Microdata Schema.org requirements?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37492875/1591669)
- [Omitting price property for sold products?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37793665/1591669)
- [Use Schema.org for Article without image property?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39035905/1591669)
- [Image missing and required - Wordpress AMP Structure doesn't add Image attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35711711/1591669)

On Webmasters SE:

- [Schema.org BlogPosting and image required](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/83303/17633)
- [Is it mandatory to have rich snippets for AMP pages?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/90897/17633)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I just checked your links above, now I understand more about how markup works. With the same markup property I curently can provide for my article, I'll get "red" with Schema.org, but I can get "green" witth Microformats `hentry`, so I guess for now I'll use `hentry` instead. However, I'll still use Schema.org `SiteNavigationElement` and `breadcrumb`. Actually also like to add `relatedLink`, but it'll be weird if using `WebPage` with only 1 property on it. And also, my related links already have header tagging.

Comment: @somuch72: If it does not cause additional effort, I would keep the Schema.org markup in addition to Microformats. All big search engines support Schema.org, while support for Microformats is not that great and probably fading (as far as I know, Google doesn’t even document anymore that they recognize Microformats like `hentry`).