# Schema.org microdata - navigation nested ItemList (Google validation error)

Tags: html, validation, schema.org, microdata

Everybody knows about microdata, but nobody knows how and when to use it properly. After searching through different StackOverflow questions and Google results I came up with following structure.

```html
<nav itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
  <ul itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemList">
    <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
      <meta itemprop="position" content="1">
      <a href="http://example.com/page1" itemprop="url">
        <span itemprop="name">Page 1</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
       <meta itemprop="position" content="2">
       <a href="http://example.com/page2" itemprop="url">
         <span itemprop="name">Page 2</span>
       </a>
       <ul itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemList">
         <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
           <meta itemprop="position" content="1">
           <a href="http://example.com/page2-1" itemprop="url">
             <span itemprop="name">Page 2-1</span>
           </a>
         </li>
         <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
           <meta itemprop="position" content="2">
           <a href="http://example.com/page2-2" itemprop="url">
             <span itemprop="name">Page 2-2</span>
           </a>
         </li>
       </ul>
     </li>
   </ul>
 </nav>
```

The only problem that I have is that I'm getting "Multiple ItemList markups on a page are not allowed" error from Google Testing Tool: https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool

Every other schema.org validator is fine with this. Is there mistake in my code or in Google Tool?

**Update:** it seems that Google just doesn't like that there is several item-list on the page. That's definetely against schema.org standarts. If I place this code two times I get the same error.

```
<ul itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemList">
  <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
    <meta itemprop="position" content="1">
    <a title="Page 1" href="http://example.com/page1" itemprop="url">
      <span itemprop="name">Page 1</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Google Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) isn’t a general Schema.org checker. Most of the warnings/errors are about rich results in Google Search.

For example, the [Carousels rich result](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/mark-up-listings) makes use of `ItemList`, so the error could mean that your page doesn’t qualify for getting this rich result in Google’s search results. If you don’t want to (or can’t) get this rich result, [you can ignore the error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41418157/1591669).

Schema.org doesn’t restrict how often a type can be used in a document.